# Generate array from comma-separated value string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is sent to my JavaScript via PHP that looks like this:

```
var string = "[ 'string 1','string 2 ','string 3' ]"
```

I want to split this string and get rid of the symbols `[`, `]` and `'` to produce the array

```
var array = {
    string 1, 
    string 2,
    string 3,
}
```

My current method uses a bunch of replaces, splits and loops. It seems very inefficient, and I want a better/more efficient method.

Comment: Arrays use `[`, not `{`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eval()...

```
var myArray = eval("['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']");
alert(myArray[0]);
```

Comment: `(new Function('return ' + myArray))`

Comment: @Scott It may work, but the other two answers are safer, more efficient, and more modern.

Comment: guys seriously, I don't mean to be a **** but this is not sensible (see my answer)

Comment: You guys are right, eval() can be dangerous and if you are unsure about the source, I'd recommend going with JSON.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to parse a JSON string.

Use a JSON parser:

```
var array = JSON.parse(str);
```

For older browsers, you should include a [JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).  (Newer browsers have it built-in)

Answer (score 3):

What? Is everyone insane?!

```
var array = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'];
```

Comment: the thing about doing that is the string gets read as individual characters like array[0] gives me [ and array[1] gives me '

Comment: @Scott - you're not supposed to split or otherwise parse this - this is JSON. If you output this exact line you will get a javascript array called 'array'

Comment: +1 assuming the array 'string' is available when the page is first generated as compared to being returned from an Ajax call - which of course the OP didn't mention.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = string.split("','");
if(array.length == 1)
{
    //deal with empty or one element array
}
else{
    array[0] = array[0].substring(3);
    array[array.length() - 1] = array[array.length() - 1].substring(0, array[array.length() - 1].length() - 3);
}
```